# Nested Initializer_list template as function parameters

Tags: c++, templates

First I have the following definitions:

```
template<class T, int N = 1>
struct Wrap { typedef initializer_list<typename Wrap<T, N - 1>::Value> Value; };

template<class T>
struct Wrap<T> { typedef initializer_list<T> Value; };

template<class T, int N = 1>
using List = typename Wrap<T, N>::Value;
```

And I have the static assert success:

```
static_assert(is_same<List<int>, initializer_list<int>>::value);
```

Which means `List<int>` should be the same type as `initializer_list<int>`.

And I have the Test class:

```
template<int N>
class Test {
public:
    template<class T>
    static void check(const List<T, N> &list) { }
};
```

But when I call:

```
Test<1>::check({1, 2, 3, 4});
```

There is a compile error:

```
No matching function for call to 'Test<1>::check(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
```

But if I change `check` to:

```
template<class T>
static void check(const initializer_list<T> &list) { }
```

The above call

```
Test<1>::check({1, 2, 3, 4});
```

Compile success.

Shouldn't `List<int>` and `initializer_list<int>` be the same type?

Comment: Those on left of :: is non-deduced context.

Comment: Can you explain more? Why ```List<int>``` and ```initializer_list<int>``` have different result thought they should be the same type?

Comment: See my old answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48387973/template-parameter-cannot-be-deduced/48388193#48388193